# How to add values ​to an array when a button is clicked in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am new to React and I'm trying to click 'test' button, and add value in array (wordArr).
This is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [wordArr, setWordArr] = useState([]);
  const [cnt, setCnt] = useState(0);

  const getText = text => {
      setWordArr(wordArr => [...wordArr, text]);
      setCnt(cnt + 1);
      console.log("cnt : " + cnt);
      console.log("wordArr : " + wordArr);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={(e)=>{getText(e.target.innerText)}}>test</button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

setCnt, setWordArr in the getText function is not executed when the button is first clicked.
cnt is 0 and wordArr is empty at first.

I use React ver 18
Why isn't this function running? I wonder

Comment: What makes you think the functions are not running, didn't they produce the console logs you are reading? React state updates are asynchronously processed, so console logging the state right after enqueueing the update can only ever output the ***current*** state value, not what it ***will be*** updated to for the next render cycle.

Comment: oh okay I got it